# React router, react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm quite new to react. SO i was trying to use react router on the following nav links. Basically before adding Route, i linked the sections of the page using their ID in that if i clicked on a link on the navbar the corresponding section would be in focus. However i tried adding react router to it and only my home page is showing. working edit-(https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3StL.png)

Ive tried console log to see whether the compenent is being rendered but its not. If i move the component below footer it is loading. I'm just lost as to how to navigate it. Any help will be appreciated.
file paths (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ji4Cg.png)

using routes (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk0Kk.png)

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react- 
router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/home/navbar";
import HomePage from "./components/home/home";
import IndvShare from "./components/individualShare/indvShare";
import MonthlyCIF from "./components/monthlyCIF/monthlyCIF";
import RepaymentDetails from "./components/repayments/repdets";
import Footer from "./components/home/contactUs";

const appRouter = () => {
return (
<Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
    <Route path="/individualShare" element={<IndvShare />} />
    <Route path="/monthlyCIF" element={<MonthlyCIF />} />
    <Route path="/repayment-details" element={<RepaymentDetails />} />
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</Router>
);
};

export default appRouter;
```

Console logging the component to see whether it rendered
Moving the component to a different position which it rendered

[Initial project before adding react router](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/MwangiR/niyo-website/draft/beautiful-bash?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fconfig%2FsupabaseConfig.js&selection=%5B%7B%22endColumn%22%3A55%2C%22endLineNumber%22%3A3%2C%22startColumn%22%3A55%2C%22startLineNumber%22%3A3%7D%5D&workspace=%257B%2522activeFilepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FcontactUs.js%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252Fconfig%252FsupabaseConfig.js%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clggbk6co000x2v6sjrsd9j56%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clggbk6co000x2v6sjrsd9j56%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clggbuacs00992v6sphtlml0y%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2523contact%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clggbu53l005c2v6srfpkblll%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clggbk6co000x2v6sjrsd9j56%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522clggbk6co000x2v6sjrsd9j56%2522%255D%252C%2522hideCodeEditor%2522%253Afalse%257D)

Comment: can you refer to this example? I think its pretty similar and its working. https://codepen.io/jonvadillo/pen/yXvxBb

Comment: What is the issue or problem you are asking for help with? You seem to be asking for help linking to your routes, but didn't include any code to show what you are trying to link and navigate to. You mention section ids so I'm going to assume you are trying to use hash links and navigate to specific sections on the ***same*** page instead of different pages entirely. Please [edit] the post to clarify the issue in better details and include a more complete [mcve] so we can see what the code is doing overall.

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed the codesandbox you shared a link to doesn't appear to exist, the page returns a 404 message. You might get more traction on your post if you fix this discrepancy.

Answer (score -1):

```
> import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"; import { BrowserRouter,
> Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"; import Layout from
> "./pages/Layout"; import Home from "./pages/Home"; import Blogs from
> "./pages/Blogs"; import Contact from "./pages/Contact"; import NoPage
> from "./pages/NoPage";
> 
> export default function App() {   return (
>     <BrowserRouter>
>       <Routes>
>         <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
>           <Route index element={<Home />} />
>           <Route path="blogs" element={<Blogs />} />
>           <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
>           <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
>         </Route>
>       </Routes>
>     </BrowserRouter>   ); }
> 
> const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
> root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: <Link to="/">Home</Link> add please like this in navebar

Comment: Hi, I attached a sandbox link to better illustrate what i mean. Rather i want to acieve the same navigation aspect of current nav bar but as well as be able to add mre that one page.